# Canvas, overlay img color on ctx.drawImage

Tags: html, canvas

I would like to overlay img color on ctx.drawImage.
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF", doesnt work on image writing.

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Im writing not regular shape images, with alpha channel, to create USA map.
And I want to color every state on different collor.

I'm writing images to canvas like that in loop:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("map-canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

for (var i = 1; i <= pvp.statesCount; i++) {
    var prefix = (i < 10) ? '0' : ''; 
    pvp.states[i] = './assets/Map/state_'+prefix+i+'.png';

    var img=document.getElementById(pvp.states[i]);
    ctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
```

Comment: context.fillStyle is like CSS color styling--it doesn't actually draw anything--it just sets the canvas's "brush" color. What you need to do is create path commands that outlines one state and then call context.fillStyle and context.fill to fill that state-path with your desired color. Repeat for every state. Here's a canvas map for every USA state that was created with paths: http://dougx.net/map/.

Comment: Thanx! You'v helped me alot! Now I can draw every state with fill, without redrawing whole map.

Comment: Maybe you'd want to try some of these operations as well, at a later date if your map has image data you're wishing to draw on top of:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing